# Simplifying a T(n) runtime

Tags: algorithm, runtime, analysis

Given the following function

```
int g(int y) {
  if (y <= 0) {
    return 1;
  } 
  else {
    return g(y-1) + g(y-2) + g(y-3);
  }
}
```

We need to find the `T(n)` run time. Now, I know that you can write

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3) + 1
```

I'm just not sure if you can simplify this any further, such as `T(n) = 3T(n-1) + 1`?

Comment: Order, or exact? The order analysis is easy; the exact analysis involves the Tribonacci sequence.

Comment: Hmm, can we write this as matrix equations for a linear system?

Comment: Yes, you can. Actually, that's how you can solve most linear recurrences. The exact solution is given by just diagonalizing the resulting recurrence matrix.

Comment: @nneonneo: Yeah, it was more of a suggestion to the OP than an actual question :) thanks though!

Comment: This is the introduction to recursive analysis, so I'm guessing it will be order. However, you should note that I'm not looking for O(n) or theta(n), I merely need to find the T(n) run time.

Comment: @NickNicolini: "merely find the T(n) run time"... O(n) is easier to find than T(n), not harder!

Comment: Yeah, T(n) means *exact* running time, O(n) would be finding the order of T(n) (which is much easier).

Comment: Wikipedia has decent explanations of [turning non-homogeneous recurrence relations into homogeneous ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_non-homogeneous_recurrence_relations), and then [solving  linear homogeneous recurrence relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).

Comment: A different perspective on similar math can be found [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/State-Space_Equations#Matrices:_A_B_C_D) and [here (starting on page 195, and specifically page 210)](http://leevaraiya.org/releases/LeeVaraiya_DigitalV2_02.pdf#page=213).

Comment: I think you guys may be over thinking this a bit. As I had previous said we have just been introduced to recursive run time analysis. For this problem, we do not need to solve the recurrence relation, only write it down

Comment: You guys would be extremely helpful if I needed to actually solve it though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let **S(n) = T(n) + 1/2**, then **S(n) = S(n-1) + S(n-2) + S(n-3)**.

Then **T(n)** should be **c<sub>1</sub> x<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup> + c<sub>2</sub> x<sub>2</sub><sup>n</sup> + c<sub>3</sub> x<sub>3</sub><sup>n</sup> - 1/2**, where **x<sub>i</sub>** are roots of equation **x<sup>3</sup> - x<sup>2</sup> - x - 1 = 0** and **c<sub>i</sub>** are specific coefficients.

The accurate solution of **T(n)** is a bit complex. Actually **x<sub>1</sub> = 1.84, x<sub>2</sub>,x<sub>3</sub> = -0.42 ± 0.61i** (yes, they are not real numbers).

However, if **T(n)** can be simplified to form like **T(n) = 3T(n-1) + 1**, then **T(n)** must be like **c<sub>1</sub> x<sup>n</sup> + c<sub>0</sub>**. Therefore, you cannot simplify it any further.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is not

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3) + 1
```

It is

```
if n > 2
    T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3)
or 
    T(n) = 1, 3, 5 for n = 0, 1, 2 respectively.
```

To check, run your original function with the following 'y's

```
g(0) = 1
g(1) = 3
g(2) = 5

g(3) = 9 (i.e. = g(0) + g(1) + g(2) = 9, not g(1) + g(2) + g(3) + 1 = 10)
```

Use dynamic programming to avoid recalculating already calculated T(n)s

```
int g(int y)
{
    if(y <= 0)
        return 1;

    if(y ==  1)
        return 3;

    if(y == 2)
        return 5;

    int a1 = 1; int a2 = 3; int a3 = 5;
    int ret = 1;

    for(int i = 2; i < y; ++i)
    {
        ret = a1 + a2 + a3;
        a1 = a2;
        a2 = a3;
        a3 = ret;
    }

    return ret;
}
```